# SQL to SAS ODBC connection - truncation of NVARCHAR(max) but getting ERROR: The option dbtype is not a valid output data set option

Tags: sql-server, sas, odbc

I have a table stored in SQL Server Management Studio version 15.0.18369.0 and I have a working and established ODBC connection to SAS language program World Programming Software version 3.4.

Previous import/reading of this data has been successful but the operator of the SQL server may have recently converted their data type to NVARCHAR(max). It may also be due to a driver change (I got a new laptop and reinstalled what I thought was the exact same OBDC for SQl driver as I had before but who knows) I have 64-bit ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server.
The VARCHAR(max) type in SQL causes the data to only be 1 character long in every column.

I have tried to fix it by:

Adding the DB max text option to libname

```
libname odbclib odbc dsn="xxx" user="xxx" password="xxx" DBMAX_TEXT=8000;
```

This did nothing so I also tried to add DB type option:

```
data mydata  (dbtype=(mycol='char(25)')) ;
    set odbclib.'sql data'n
run;
```

And I get ERROR:

> The option dbtype is not a valid output data set option.

I have also tried DBSASTYPE, and putting both options in the set statement and this yields the same error.

I also tried with proc SQL:

```
proc sql noprint;
 CONNECT TO ODBC(dsn="xxx" user="xxx" password="xxx");  create table
 extract(compress=no dbsastype=(mycol='CHAR(20)')) as   select * from
 connection to odbc     (       select * from dbo.'sql data'n 
            );  disconnect from odbc; quit;
```

And I get

> NOTE: Connected to DB: BB64 (Microsoft SQL Server version 12.00.2148)
> NOTE: Successfully connected to database ODBC as alias ODBC. 3915
> create table extract(compress=no
> dbsastype=(mycol='CHAR(20)')) as 3916          select *
> from connection to odbc 3917          ( 3918              select *
> from dbo.'sql data'n ERROR: The option dbsastype is not a valid
> output data set option 3919               3920          ); 3921
> disconnect from odbc; NOTE: ERRORSTOP was specified. The statement
> will not be executed due to an earlier error NOTE: Statements not
> executed because of errors detected 3922      quit;

Comment: Did you try modifying your second example so that the dataset option is on the dataset that is coming from the library that is using the ODBC engine instead of on the dataset you are writing to the WORK library with BASE SAS engine?  Like the message implies?

Comment: Thank you the workaround is successful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try would be putting the DBTYPE or DBSASTYPE in the right place.

```
data mydata;
    set odbclib.'sql data'n(dbtype=(mycol='char(25)'));
run;
```

It is an option that would go on the "set" not the "data" line.

I would also encourage you to contact the developers, as it seems like this is a bug in their implementation; or perhaps try a different ODBC SQL driver.

Maybe a workaround in the meanwhile is to use CONVERT in the passthrough?

```
proc sql noprint;
 CONNECT TO ODBC(dsn="xxx" user="xxx" password="xxx");  create table
 extract as   select * from
 connection to odbc     (       select a,b,c,convert(NCHAR(20),mycol) from dbo.'sql data'n 
            );  disconnect from odbc; quit;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added this to the set statement, the code runs with no errors but the values are still truncated. I will contact the developers as per your suggestion.

Comment: @a1ballc2 Consider my edited workaround for the time being - I think you can force it in the passthrough query to be not nvarchar(max) with `CONVERT`.